# How to deploy program to solana

Tags: solana-program, bug

I am attempting to run the HelloWorld Solana program. I started the project with

```
solana-test-validator
```

I ran `npm install` and then was able to build the rust project.
I can see the .so file in the directory /dist/program/helloworld.so. When I try to deploy the program to Solana, I run

```
solana program deploy dist/program/helloworld.so
```

And here is the error I get

```
Error: Dynamic program error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

What else should I try?

Comment: If you are sure you can view the .so directory, perhaps you could check if your wallet is configured correctly, if not you could try running `solana-keygen new` to create a new [file wallet](https://docs.solana.com/cli/conventions#file-system-wallet) in your local machine

Answer (score 3):

First, use the

```
npm run build:program-rust(or any file that contains your rust src)
```

command to compile your program to a file with the so file extension.
(Run

```
solana-keygen new
```

to create and save a solana keypair locally.)
Set up your localnet with the command (that should now be in your PATH)

```
solana-test-validator
```

When calling

```
solana config get
```

your "RPC URL" should now equal http://localhost:8899. If not, run

```
solana config set --url http://localhost:8899
```

Running

```
solana balance
```

will show your balance which should NOT be 0. If it is, stop the validators, make sure you have created a key with `solana-keygen` new and start it again from genesis with `solana-test-validator -r`.
Then, run

```
solana logs
```

to see all the interactions with your local cluster.
Use the

```
solana program deploy /(your project name)/dist/program/helloworld.so
```

to deploy your program to localnet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `solana-test-validator` is running

- `cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program`

this will create the output in `dist/program`

- `solana-keygen new -o ./wallets/Owner.json`
  this will spit an address like `"Be4PYPjaKFYsZN847SFBEPm6UNErfRD8qrCZ1rfn6rUw"` on terminal
- `solana airdrop 2 Be4PYPjaKFYsZN847SFBEPm6UNErfRD8qrCZ1rfn6rUw`
- `solana deploy dist/program/directoryName_program.so` - this will spit out this on terminal: `"Program Id: 7zkE9MbN4yDybYP9j19kmZjTA855SMh2kFW2C1Pj8EHN"`

[.so stands for 'shared object'](https://www.lifewire.com/so-file-4150722)